# Как восстановить данные с ntfs раздела после форматирования?

Tags: ntfs, recovery

Отформатировал важный диск и поставил на него `Windows`. Как восстановить данные?

Comment: See here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31377/19806 (Sorry, I don't speak Russian... maybe someone might volunteer and write a summary here as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала - физически его отрубить и найти ещё один, куда будешь восстанавливать файлы. Потом взять или windows livecd, где есть программы `R-Studio`, `Active@ File Recovery`, `R.Saver`. Или если livecd на базе linux, то смотреть в сторону программы `TestDisk`. Проводить режим глубокого\полного сканирования. Ну и молиться, чтобы установленная ОС не залезла физически на те кластеры, на которых была важная информация.