# Последствия после клонирования диска

Tags: windows, клонирование

Добрый день!

На одном томе жесткого диска (160 Гб) начали сыпаться кластера, решил  его скопировать на другой hdd размером 1,5 Тб (из них свободных 168 Гб). Воспользовался для этого программой Ontrack EasyRecovery. Но то ли я не то нажал, то ли недопонял смысл содеянного, мой 1.5 террабайтный диск превратился в 160 гб. Вопрос как вернуть данные, которые были до копирования на диске 1.5 Тб?

При восстановлении разделов и файлов на диске 1,5 Тб показывает файлы удаленные с диска 160 Гб, поэтому простое восстановление файлов не помогает.

Comment: Вернуть кого? 
Если на windows то в разделе администрирование/управление дисками. Там можно добавить еще один раздел. А если нужно восстановить старую таблицу разделов, то можно через Acronis

Comment: подозреваю, что просто были скопированы первые 160 Гб один в один на новый диск (то есть, посекторным копированием). В этом случае как раз и будет наблюдаться вышеуказанная проблема.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как эту проблему решить, на диске хранились фото и видео за последние 15 лет...  пробовал восстановить том, но старый том не находит,так же пробовал восстановление данных - показывает удаленные данные с диска 160 гб, т.е. как будто 1,5 Тб не существовало...

Comment: Вообще говоря, этот вопрос - оффтопик, он не относится к программированию или профессиональному администрированию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как восстановить данные с ntfs раздела после форматирования?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523590/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-ntfs-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: ситуации к сожалению разные, как такового форматирования я не производил, программами восстанавливать тоже пробовал, восстанавливает файлы которые были удалены с жесткого 160 Гб. Ну а за оффтоп прошу прощения, я здесь с вопросом первый раз, не знал где еще можно спросить.

Comment: @kentaskis, если "deep scan" не помогает, то скорее всего всё. Ищи старые бэкапы.

Comment: Я бы ещё попробовал с хирургической точностью занулить ту область, куда записался 160ГБ образ (естественно, предварительно скопировав его на какой-то другой диск), чтобы помочь программам восстановления понять реальную картину. Но нужно понимать что к чему, иначе лучше не пытаться.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, данные с 1.5ТБ диска никак не восстановить "Домашними" средствами, т.к. Вы стерли таблицу разделов и перезаписали поверх старой разметки данные. Единственный вариант, как я вижу, обратиться в специализированную организацию по восстановлению данных.

Comment: То, что потёрлась таблица - это не страшно. И что данные поверх записались - не факт. Нужно смотреть через спец софт. Каждый случай уникален.