# Не загружается linux

Tags: ubuntu, grub, gparted, live-usb

На ноуте hhd с виндой и ssd с линуксом. Через линукс ставил на флешку .iso образ kali с помощью утилиты dd. После завершения вынул флешку. Но в проводнике осталось все равно устройство флешки. При перезагрузке ноутбука вылез консоль grub. Загрузившись с флешки (уже с ubuntu), зашел в gparted и увидел такое чудо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможноли восстановить систему? Или хотябы файлы?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523603/191416, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457232/191416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по скрину вы диск перепутали и попробовали поставить kali. Восстановить данные можно, вот OS, маловероятно.
http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: Спасибо, за ссылку, действительно полезная утилита TestDisk. Сохранил свои файлы на всякий случай с помощью этой утилиты и воспользовался этим руководством - [Восстановление разделов и данных в Linux](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/admin/data-recovery/recovery.html). В итоге: восстановленная система без каких либо потерь.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo testdisk-6.9/linux/testdisk_static` поможет найти разделы